# Is there a special term for the two variables in a Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, terminology, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Say I have a function $F(x)$ whose Fourier transform is $G(y)$. Is there a special term to refer to the two variables $x, y$?

I'm thinking it might be called "Fourier counterpart" or something, but I can't find anything to confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such variables related through Fourier transforms are known as [conjugate variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables).